# How do I fetch data from an endpoint everytime I click a button? In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am trying to learn React and I have to do an app that generates random quotes when a button is clicked. I have a problem when trying to get data from an API and passing it to the state of the component. I searched the internet but all I could found was that in React, most API calls are made inside `componentDidMount`, but that doesn't help at all. I need to make a call to the endpoint every time the button is clicked.
**Edit:** I have to mention that I am using codepen.io for this. Maybe the problem is related to this. Here is the link (https://codepen.io/bogdanoprea1998/pen/abWmaWa?editors=0011)

```
const setRandomColor = () => {
  const color =
    "hsl(" +
    360 * Math.random() +
    "," +
    (25 + 70 * Math.random()) +
    "%," +
    (85 + 10 * Math.random()) +
    "%)";
  $("#quote-box").css("background-color", color);
};

class QuoteApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      author: "Satya Nadella",
      quote: "This is a software-powered world.",
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  //Handlers
  handleClick() {
    fetch("http://quotable.io/random")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          return {
            author: data.author,
            quote: data.content,
          };
        });
      });
    setRandomColor();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://quotable.io/random")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          return {
            author: data.author,
            quote: data.content,
          };
        });
      });
    setRandomColor();
  }
  //Error handling
  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    console.log(error, errorInfo);
  }

  render() {
    const tweetLink = `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=${this.state.quote} -${this.state.author}`;
    return (
      <div id="quote-box">
        <h2 id="text">{this.state.quote}</h2>
        <h3 id="author">{this.state.author}</h3>
        <a className="twitter-share-button" href={tweetLink} id="tweet-quote">
          Tweet
        </a>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick} id="new-quote">
          Next
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<QuoteApp />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Are you getting errors? You may want to have a method called `getData` so you don't have to repeat code. Have `componentDidMount` call that (once), and have your `handleClick` method call it too.

Comment: I couldn't really see anything particularly wrong with your code but I did notice that you're trying to use jQuery with it which is not a good idea.

Comment: I am not getting any errors, but when I press the button the text doesn't change. Maybe the component updates before the API can send the response? Also, I only used jQuery for randomizing the color and that part works as intended.

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you added logging to make sure the function is called? Have you logged the data it gets back from the API to make sure it is actually different?

Comment: The function is called because the color of the background is changing when I press the button. Also, logs inside the fetch function are not displaying anything in the console for some reason. If I paste the API link in the browser directly it returns the JSON that I need. So I tried all I could think of, but didn't manage to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your code, and the code looks good. I believe the issue is with the API URL that you use.
Try to use this instead https://api.quotable.io/random. It will work now